# How do I combine dataframe (pandas) columns to plot confidence intervals in a Seaborn box plot?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn

My dataframe looks something like this:

[image: Dataframe with 4 rows and N columns]

I want to combine `Column 1` and `Column 2` by making a confidence interval (take the mean of `Column 1` and `Column 2,` find the standard deviation, etc.) and then plot that using Seaborn box plots. Basically, I want to compare the values across the 4 rows (each row is an experimental subject) for each value (but each value has multiple measurements). In other words, I need to combine columns (replicate experiments) in the DataFrame. How would I go about doing this?

Here is what I'm hoping to get:

[image: Box Plot]

Thanks!